# are there any conditional restart library implementations for java/clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

I've found an implementation for ruby, and its builtin on CL and dylan. Is there anything like this that runs on the jvm?

http://axisofeval.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/whats-condition-system-and-why-do-you.html

http://github.com/archit/restarts

http://opendylan.org/documentation/intro-dylan/conditions.html#handlers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [swell](https://github.com/hugoduncan/swell) is what you are looking for. Get it from [Clojars](https://clojars.org/swell).

Answer (score 0):

I implemented one myself to learn more about techniques

http://z.caudate.me/ribol/